# Dynamic data in bar chart not rendering React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, chart.js

I'm trying to fetch data from a database and render it as the x-axis labels in a bar chart.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styling/ClassGrades.css";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import Axios from "axios";

function ClassGrades() {
    let studentsArray = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/getStudentsFromClass", {
            params: { currentClassClicked }
        }).then(response => {
            setStudents(response.data.message);
            // console.log(response.data.message)
            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.message.length; i++) {
                studentsArray.push(String(response.data.message[i].firstName));
            }
            console.log(studentsArray);

            // console.log(response.data.message[0].firstName)
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(studentsArray);

    const currentClassClicked = localStorage.getItem("currentClassClicked");
    console.log(currentClassClicked);
    const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
    return (
        <div className="class-grades-container">
            <h1>{currentClassClicked}</h1>
            <Bar
                data={{
                    labels: studentsArray,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "student grades",
                            data: [30, 80, 20, 10]
                        }
                    ]
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default ClassGrades;
```

I created an array and in the `useEffect` hook, each of the data is added to the `studentsArray` but it doesn't render in the bar chart. I console logged the array, and the data is all there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React renders when state and props of the component change. `studentsArray` is an array that is not a state nor a prop. So react doesn't know about the changes you have made. Follow these steps to get reflection of the data

### Create state for student list

You need to store student list in state of the component

```
const [list, setList] = useState([])
```

### Set state in fetching logic

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const studentsArray = []; 
        Axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/getStudentsFromClass", {
            params: {currentClassClicked}
        }).then((response) => {
            setStudents(response.data.message)
            // console.log(response.data.message)
            for (let i = 0; i<response.data.message.length; i++){
                studentsArray.push(String(response.data.message[i].firstName))
            }
            setList(studentsArray)
        })
    }, [])
```

### Use list in chart

Use state list in DOM

```
 return (
        <div className='class-grades-container'>
            <h1>{currentClassClicked}</h1>
                <Bar 
                    data={{
                        labels: list,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "student grades",
                                data: [30, 80, 20, 10]
                            }
                        ]
                    }}
                />
        </div>
    )
```